# Integrate drools with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rule-engine

Have any of you ever integrated the JBoss rules engine into a rails app using JRuby?

Comment: No. But what is the problem?. Reusing java libraries in rails is where  JRuby shines. We load Axis2, HttpClient, CXF etc in our rails app with no issues. And then we run all of that in tomcat using jruby-rack ( no warbler). Had to add a few jar files in tomcat/lib/endorsed though.